# Forcing fullpage.js to scroll to the top of long sections when scrolling from the bottom to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, fullpage.js

So I have implemented fullpage.js on my page, and everything seems to be working with the exception of one thing:

When I scroll from the bottom of the page and work upward, the page seems to choose to use the bottom of sections (as opposed to the top of sections) as the reference for keyboard scrolling.  Because I have deliberately included long sections (longer than a fullpage, which I want to keep) **this means that when I scroll below the long sections, and then back up to them, the display lands on the bottom half (instead of the top half) of these long sections.** This is not desirable.

My questions:

1) Am I correct in ascertaining that fullpage.js is using these bottom of slides as reference for scrolling from the bottom of the page, upward?

and

2) Do any of you know of a fix I can implement that will allow me to make the plugin scroll to the top of the preceding slide, when scrolling from below, instead of aligning the preceding section's bottom to the bottom of my screen?

I believe this is an issue that others wishing to retain long sections might also confront, so any help would be likely not only be very much appreciated by me but also by others.
Here is a [link to fullpage.js](https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.js):

Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/ihatecoding/pen/grgaxr

Here are my fullpage.js Settings:

```
 $('#fullpage').fullpage({
          sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', '#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE'],
          scrollBar: true,
          fitToSection:false,
          sectionSelector: 'section',
          scrollingSpeed: 300,
          paddingTop: '100px',
          verticalCentered:true,
          fixedElements: '#headerCont'
       });
```

Here is my HTML (you can see the CSS on the codepen if you want):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <article>
<div id = "fullpage">

<div id= "headerCont">
<div id = "header">

<div id="topWrapper"></div>

 <table id="lastRow" class="home">
<tr>
  <td id ="finalCell">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
</div>


  <section>


  <h1 class="divider">Section1</h1>
      <div id = "about" class = "mainSub">

      <div id="mainImage" class="imgDiv introCell">
      </div>

      <div id = "nameTitle" class="introCell">

      </div>


      </div>

    </section>

      <section>

      <div id = "previews" class = "mainSub">
      <!-- <section> -->
      <h1 class="divider">Section2</h1>


  <div class="grid bg eCell">
     <div class="gridContent">
          <div class="gridTable">
              <div class="gridTable-cell">
                  Stuff<br>1
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid bg stemCell">
      <div class="gridContent">
          <div class="gridTable">
              <div class="gridTable-cell stem">
                  Stuff<br>2
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid bg eCell">
     <div class="gridContent">
          <div class="gridTable">
              <div class="gridTable-cell">
                  Stuff<br>3
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid bg stemCell">
      <div class="gridContent">
          <div class="gridTable">
              <div class="gridTable-cell stem">
                  Stuff<br>4
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>


      </div>


      <!-- </section> -->
    </section>






   <section>
      <div id = "contactDiv" class = "mainSub">
        <!--  <section> -->


        <h1><a name="contact" class="anchor">Section3</a></h1>
        <div id = "contactInfo" class = "contactContentWrapper sectionContentWrapper">


      <div = "phoneDiv" class = "contactMethodDiv">
        <span id="PhoneTitle" class = "contactTitle">Phone:</span><a href="tel:5555555555"><span>555 555 5555 </span></a>
      </div>

      </div>
        <!-- </section> -->
      </div>
    </section>



    <section>

    <div id="staffDiv">
      <h1>Section4</h1>
      <ul id ="staffPlural">
        <li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div>
        </li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff">
          <span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person
          </div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div>
          </li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li>
      </ul>

    </div>


    <div id="staffDiv">
      <ul id ="staffPlural">
        <li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div>
        </li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff">
          <span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person
          </div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div>
          </li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="staffDiv">
      <ul id ="staffPlural">
        <li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div>
        </li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff">
          <span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person
          </div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div>
          </li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="staffDiv">
      <ul id ="staffPlural">
        <li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div>
        </li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff">
          <span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person
          </div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div>
          </li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <div id="staffDiv">
      <ul id ="staffPlural">
        <li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div>
        </li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff">
          <span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">persond</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person
          </div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div>
          </li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li>
      </ul>

    </div>


    <div id="staffDiv">

      <ul id ="staffPlural">
        <li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div>
        </li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff">
          <span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person
          </div></li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div>
          </li><li class ="staff"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">person</div></li>
      </ul>

    </div>


    </section>


    <section id="footerSection">
    <div id = "eFooter" class = "footer areaSub">
      <div id = "eFooterContentWrapper" class = "footerContentWrapper sectionContentWrapper">

    <ul id="eFooterList" class ="footerList">
        <li><a>footerA</a></li>
        <li><a>footerB</a></li>
        <li><a>footerC</a></li>
    </ul>

    </div>
    </div>
  </section>









</div>
      </article>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Related with https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1854

Comment: I tried the fix suggested at that page, but it did not work for me, I posted the version of the edited file with the gitHub user Niklas's suggestion here: https://github.com/codercooooder/fullpageScrollFixes/blob/master/jquery.niklasFullPageFix.js.  Did I do something wrong? I did not see any indication that they changed anything else or altered any other settings.